# Good answers spread in multiple duplicates

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

All these questions are nearly exactly duplicate of each other:

[Prevent that a fixed element resizes when zooming on touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233076/prevent-that-a-fixed-element-resizes-when-zooming-on-touchscreen)  [5 answers]

[How to prevent (bootstrap) fixed top navigation from zooming on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27983673/1422096) [2 answers, the first one looks promising]

[Zoom specific element on webcontent (HTML,CSS,JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782465/zoom-specific-element-on-webcontent-html-css-javascript) [2 answers]

[Pinch/zoom within a div but not whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14715595/1422096) [closed, 1 answer]

[Disable zoom on a div, but allow zoom on the page (an alternate div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div) [4 answers]

[Pinch-to-zoom, but only in a specific div (not full page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775050/pinch-to-zoom-but-only-in-a-specific-div-not-full-page) [closed, duplicate]

How to deal with such situations, in which 12 answers are spread in various questions?

Is it possible to merge them?

Or to link them to each other?

---

Edit: I know the process of merging / etc. has already been discussed on meta.SO, but as I'm not very experienced with suck kind of task, could someone help?

Comment: I know this that question about question merging has already been discussed, but I'm really too unexperimented to handle such a complex situation involving 6 or 7 questions. Could you reopen the question (the linked questions don't give a concrete example about how to achieve this)? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What about the linked questions failed to describe what to do?  Both of them specifically describe the steps for how questions are merged.  There's no reason to reopen a question just to repeat the same information yet again.

Comment: @Servy: it's just that with my very low current experience in moderation, I won't be able to handle this myself alone. (Never mind if nobody has time to have a look, but I wanted to give attention about these topics).

Comment: I have complete faith in your ability to cast one flag without anyone needing to help you.  If you try, and have problems *then* feel free to ask for help, explaining what specific problem you're having.